# Unable to bundle app with libusb1 in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, libusb-1.0

I'm running Python 2.7.12 with a simple python file and importing a couple of modules (PyQt5 and usb1). No additional assets or files.

When I try to bundle the app, with a default spec file, the app works fine on my host machine. But trying to run it on another machine (with Python 2.7.10) fails with this error: OSError: dlopen(libusb-1.0.dylib, 6): image not found. So I added the following in the spec file in Analysis object :

```
binaries=[('/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib', 'libusb-1.0.0.dylib')],
```

Doesn't work either. Any help with getting libusb1 to work with PyInstaller bundle? I'm using OSX 10.10.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally solved it! 
I manually copied the libusb-1.0.0.dylib from /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/ and pasted/overwrote the one in the distributed folder. Then created a symlink in the folder as libusb-1.0.dylib and that seemed to do it. Hope this helps someone!